# ReactNative / Momentjs date parsing issue

Tags: javascript, react-native, momentjs

Using momentjs with React Native. The `MomentT` function below is parsing the date / time as per the requested format and it's showing up formatted correctly, but it's giving me a bizarre time, instead of the time of the sunset. It actually seems to be ignoring `json.sys.sunset` (which in LA currently is roughly 1470969909 in unix time) and parsing it as 4:36:09 pm, but it should parse it as 7:45:09 PM. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the relevant code:

```
var moment = require('moment');

var MomentT = function(tod) {
  return moment(tod).format('h:mm:ss a');
};  

module.exports = function(latitude, longitude) {
  var url = `${rootUrl}&lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}`;
  console.log(url);
  return fetch(url)
    .then(function(response){
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(json){
      return {
        sunset: MomentT(json.sys.sunset)
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
    throw error;
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse tod in [new Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) as below

```
var MomentT = function(tod) {
  return moment(new Date(tod)).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
};
```

As per [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) 1st argument must be a datestring

Answer (score 1):

`moment(Number)` requires that the timestamp is the number of *milliseconds* since the epoch. You're passing in seconds, so you're ending up with a date somewhere in 1970.

Two solutions:

```
moment(tod * 1000)
moment.unix(tod)
```

Documented [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) and [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/).